# Multiple fixed values in a dtd element

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm trying to define a DTD for an XML. This XML have an element hidden whose value can be 0 o 1. Is it possible to represent this in DTD? I'm reading W3C tutorial and elements can have a sequence but I only can use other elements inside.

Comment: I thought you can't do this by using DTD. instead you could try XSD.

Comment: [XSD-Int-Restrictions](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp)